# Can I run ubuntu without loading it to a harddrive?

Tags: live-usb, live-cd

Can I run Ubuntu from CD or a memory stick?

Comment: yes,you can run ubuntu without installing it into hard drive.

Comment: Take a look at [Try Ubuntu before you install it](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

I assume you are currently running Windows, here are the instructions on how to [create a bootable USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

In case I'm wrong about Windows, here are the instructions for [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) and [OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx).